# how to convert android popups to glass activities\cards?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, google-gdk

I write an android app with activity and popups which i can scroll between them.

my popups have custom layout (not plain text card)

I want to adjust it to glass style.

I want each popup to be seen as a full screen view. how would you advise me to do so?

1) should i use cards in a cardsScrollView?
(but my popup has a few buttons and I want to scroll between them by glass gestures)

like this?

```
public class CardScrollActivity extends Activity {

private List<Card> mCards;
private CardScrollView mCardScrollView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    createCards();

    mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
    ExampleCardScrollAdapter adapter = new ExampleCardScrollAdapter();
    mCardScrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mCardScrollView.activate();
    setContentView(mCardScrollView);
}

private void createCards() {
    mCards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    Card card;

    card = new Card(this);
    card.setText("This card has a footer.");
    card.setFootnote("I'm the footer!");
    mCards.add(card);

    card = new Card(this);
    card.setText("This card has a puppy background image.");
    card.setFootnote("How can you resist?");
    card.setImageLayout(Card.ImageLayout.FULL);
    card.addImage(R.drawable.puppy_bg);
    mCards.add(card);

    card = new Card(this);
    card.setText("This card has a mosaic of puppies.");
    card.setFootnote("Aren't they precious?");
    card.setImageLayout(Card.ImageLayout.LEFT);
    card.addImage(R.drawable.puppy_small_1);
    card.addImage(R.drawable.puppy_small_2);
    card.addImage(R.drawable.puppy_small_3);
    mCards.add(card);
}
```

2) should i use activities ?
(but how will i scroll between them?)

Comment: When developing for glass, you should not port your android app to glass without rethinking the flow/architecture. Hence it requires another UX then an application developed for phones and tablets

Comment: i have another UX, but want to use the same logic